# Subset a dataframe using multiple conditions

Tags: r, subset

How to subset a dataframe using multiple conditions?

This does exactly the opposite, and I need to include "!"

```
x<-c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")
df <- subset(df, subset = col_name %in% x)
```

Comment: Try `df[, ! names(df) %in% x]`

Comment: worked well `df <- subset(df, subset = !col_name %in% x)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter function from dplyr package.
The usual syntax is,

```
dplyr::filter(data, col1 cond, col2 cond, col3 cond....coln cond)
```

Links to other resources,

- https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dplyr/versions/0.7.3/topics/filter
- [Filter multiple conditions dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25647470/filter-multiple-conditions-dplyr)
- https://www.r-bloggers.com/dplyr-example-1/

This allows you to create conditions however you want.