# Filtering Column by Multiple values

Tags: r, filtering

I would like to filter values based on one column with multiple values.

For example, one `data.frame` has s&p `500` tickers, i have to pick `20` of them and associated closing prices. How to do it?

Comment: `df[which(df$Ticker %in% c("Ticker1", "Ticker2", "Ticker3", ...)),]`

Answer (score 3):

If I understand well you question, I believe you should do it with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
target <- c("Ticker1", "Ticker2", "Ticker3")
filter(df, Ticker %in% target)
```

The answer can be found in https://stackoverflow.com/a/25647535/9513536

Cheers !