# Trying to replace items in a vector based on an index vector

Tags: r, vector

I have a vector, SingleMeans$BinNumb, that looks something like this:

```
rSingleMeans$BinNumb <- c(1,5,6,101,106,201,206,3,6,202,211,207,4,6,105,101)
```

I'd like to code all the items in the vector that match up with codes listed in "congruent codes" as "congruent"

```r
CongruentCodes = c(101,102,103,104,109,110,111,112,201,202,203,204,209,210,211,212)
```

This is what I am trying to do:

```
SingleMean$Congruency<- ifelse(SingleMean$BinNumb[which(SingleMean$BinNumb == CongruentCodes)],"Congruent","Incongruent")
```

But it's spitting out this error and returning a null:

```
Warning message:
In SingleMean$BinNumb == CongruentCodes :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

Comment: `ifelse(SingleMean$BinNumb %in% CongruentCodes, "Congruent", "Incongruent")`

Comment: FYI, in SO code formatting, the triple-backtick `\`\`\`` must be on its own line, no code on that line before or after it.

Answer (score 0):

With a `data.frame`, the LHS and RHS of the assignment must have the same length vectors. If you subset one side, you must subset the other identically.

For instance,

```r
# this is wrong
SingleMean$Congruency <- 
  ifelse(
    SingleMean$BinNumb[which(SingleMean$BinNumb == CongruentCodes)],
    "Congruent", "Incongruent")
```

Unless the `which(.)` returns the same length, then we don't have the same side. One literal step to fix this would be:

```r
# this is likely wrong but may not error
SingleMean$Congruency[which(SingleMean$BinNumb == CongruentCodes)] <- 
  ifelse(
    SingleMean$BinNumb[which(SingleMean$BinNumb == CongruentCodes)],
    "Congruent", "Incongruent")
```

However ... I don't think that's what you need, for a couple reasons:

- `CongruentCodes` is length greater than 1, so I think you need `%in%`, see

  - [What is the difference between `%in%` and `==`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15358006/3358272)
  - [Difference between the == and %in% operators in R](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42637099/3358272)
  - [Filter multiple values on a string column in dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25647470/3358272)
- the `test=` (first) argument of `ifelse` needs a `logical` return, and I'm guessing your `$BinNumb` column is integer/numeric, not logical, so that's not quite what we want;
- I think you want to assign/update *all* values of your `Congruency` column, not just the ones that match the subset condition
- `which` can and usually will return a different length as the original data, and will only include those that match (and do nothing to the not-matching elements), remove the `which(` and `)` and you get what will return a `logical` vector the same length as the data (which is what we need); this is similar to

  - [Error - replacement has [x] rows, data has [y]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29814912/3358272)

I think you need just the `$BinNum %in% CongruentCodes` in your `test`, which will return one of the `yes=` or `no=` values based on the condition.

```r
SingleMean$Congruency <- 
  ifelse(
    SingleMean$BinNumb %in% CongruentCodes,
    "Congruent", "Incongruent")
```

The time one would use `which` might include something like this (though I prefer the `ifelse` above):

```r
# I don't think this is the best way to do it
SingleMean$Congruency <- "Incongruent"
SingleMean$Congruency <- 
  replace(SingleMean$Congruency,
          which(SingleMean$BinNumb %in% CongruentCodes),
          "Congruent")
```

(*That* code would work both with `which(. == .)` and as just `. == .`, it accepts both logical and integer (index) arguments for its second argument.)